# Creating unit tests for capacitor native android plugin

Tags: android, capacitor

I'm trying to add some android native unit tests for a capacitor plugin I created.
The problem is that the method expects to get a PluginCall object as a param. In iOS it's pretty straightforward. for example:

```
func test()
{
    let data = "madness? THIS. IS. DATA!!!!! ~Leonidas I, King of Data, around 480 BCE"
    let plugin = Plugin()

    let call = CAPPluginCall(callbackId: "test", options: [
        "data": data
    ], success: { (result, call) in
        let resultValue = result?.data["data"] as? Data
        XCTAssert(resultValue != nil)
    }, error: { (err) in
        XCTFail("Error shouldn't have been called")
    })

    plugin.doSomethingCool(call!)
}
```

Pretty simple stuff really.

Trying to do the same thing for android, doesn't work quite well. 
To instantiate a new PluginCall object I have to pass to the constructor a MessageHandler object, and to instantiate a MessageHandler object I have to pass a Bridge object, to instantiate a bridge object, I have to pass a PluginManager object that the compiler doesn't even recognise. Apparently an impossible task.
Of course I can always just replace the PluginCall param with the actual data, but I want to have a full test coverage for my plugin and not omit huge parts of it just so I can test it. Trying to search this problem online yielded no results, even the official docs doesn't say anything about it, so I turn to SO. Has anyone done something like this before and can point me in the right direction?

TL;DR

How can I create android native unit tests for a capacitor plugin?

Thanks :)

Comment: Did you figured this out?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I haven't tested it, but I think your best course of action, is to create a demo app to go with the plugin and write your tests there.

Comment: Any luck? But when we create a demo app it would be black box test of our plugin so more like e2e test of plugin and not unit testing where we test each unit in isolation